# How can I make Tikz pins appear after click

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table},t]{beamer}    

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}
        

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes,calligraphy,plotmarks,overlay-beamer-styles}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
    
\begin{figure}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(1.3,0)},draw=none,anchor= south, legend columns=1, font=\tiny,text width=1in, minimum height=0.2in}, 
ymin=0,ymax=1000,
xlabel = Strain ($\epsilon_{e}$ and $\epsilon_{t}$),
every axis x label/.style=
    {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
ylabel = Stress ($F_{t}$ and $F_{e}$),
every axis y label/.style=
    {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel},    
xmin=0, xmax=0.4,
xtick={0,0.05,...,0.4},,
x tick label style={rotate=45},
width=0.75\linewidth,
height=0.58\linewidth,
font=\tiny,    
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
]
\begin{scope}[
  every pin edge/.style={<-,>=latex, mark size=3pt},
  every pin/.append style={font=\tiny}
]



\addplot [black,mark = *,mark size=3pt,mark options={fill=black}, only marks] coordinates {(0.012,439) (0.182322,614.4) (0.2,512) (0.29,350)};

    \node [coordinate,pin={[visible on=<2->,pin distance=0.35 in,pin edge={gray,thick}]90:{(5) $F_{t}=F_{ut}*[w*\frac{\epsilon_{t}}{\epsilon_{ut}}^n+(1-w)*(1+\epsilon_{t}-\epsilon_{ut})]$} } ]
        at (axis cs:0.239017,638.115116) {};
      
    \node[coordinate,pin={[pin distance=0.25 in,pin edge={gray,thick}]90:{(4) $F_{t}=F_{ut}*(\frac{\epsilon_{t}}{\epsilon_{ut}})^n$} } ]
        at (axis cs:0.095,565) {};            

\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.03,400)
{\tiny{A}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.18,450)
{\tiny{B}};

%\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.33,350)
%{\tiny{C}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.182322,680)
{\tiny{B'}};    

\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.1,160)
{\tiny{Hardening Region}};    

\addplot [<->, black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0.012,439)  (0.012,0)};
\addplot [<->, black,dashed, thick] coordinates {(0.2,512)  (0.2,0)};
\addplot [<->, black, thick] coordinates {(0.012,100)  (0.2,100)};

\addplot [<->, black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0.29,350)  (0.29,0)};
\addplot [<->, black, thick] coordinates {(0.2,100)  (0.29,100)};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.245,160)
{\tiny{Necking}};    

    %\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.245,180)
%{\tiny$\begin{aligned} Necking, and \\ Fracture \end{aligned}$};    

\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.31,350)
{\tiny{C}}; 

\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{True Stress Strain Match}
\label{Tension_Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

TikZ nodes are overlay aware. This means you can delay the complete node, including the text and the pin, with `\node<2->`

Some other comments about your code

- figures are centred by default in beamer. No need to warp them in a center environment. This will only mess with the vertical spacing
- you don't need to define the `visible on` etc. styles yourself, that's what you load the `overlay-beamer-styles` library for
- the `frame` environment is missing. That's a crucial part of beamer. Never use beamer without a frame!

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table},t]{beamer}    

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}
        

    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes,calligraphy,plotmarks,overlay-beamer-styles}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}

%\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{axis}[
    %x label style={at=(.50,-0.1)},
    %x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    %y label style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=west},
    legend style={at={(1.3,0)},draw=none,anchor= south, legend columns=1, font=\tiny,text width=1in, minimum height=0.2in}, 
    ymin=0,ymax=1000,
    xlabel = Strain ($\epsilon_{e}$ and $\epsilon_{t}$),
    every axis x label/.style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel = Stress ($F_{t}$ and $F_{e}$),
    every axis y label/.style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel},    
    xmin=0, xmax=0.4,
    xtick={0,0.05,...,0.4},,
    x tick label style={rotate=45},
    width=0.75\linewidth,
    height=0.58\linewidth,
    font=\tiny,    
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
]
\begin{scope}[
      every pin edge/.style={<-,>=latex, mark size=3pt},
      every pin/.append style={font=\tiny}
    ]


        \node<2-> [coordinate,pin={[pin distance=0.35 in,pin edge={gray,thick}]90:{(5) $F_{t}=F_{ut}*[w*\frac{\epsilon_{t}}{\epsilon_{ut}}^n+(1-w)*(1+\epsilon_{t}-\epsilon_{ut})]$} } ] at (axis cs:0.239017,638.115116) {};
          
  
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}
\caption{True Stress Strain Match}
\label{Tension_Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Forgive me if this is off topic, hate to make a whole post for such a small question. 

How do you animate the code directly in the response like that?

Comment: That was embarrassingly simple. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @MegaStructures I compiled the document locally, then converted the pdf into an animated gif and uploaded this gif. (That's the command I use for converting: `convert -delay 30 -loop 0 -density 100 -alpha remove "document".pdf "document".gif`)

Comment: @MegaStructures You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue:

`visible on=<2->` simply needed to be added to the pin options as follows:

```
    \node [coordinate,pin={[visible on=<2->,pin distance=0.35 in,pin edge={visible on=<2->,gray,thick}]90:{(5) $F_{t}=F_{ut}*[w*\frac{\epsilon_{t}}{\epsilon_{ut}}^n+(1-w)*(1+\epsilon_{t}-\epsilon_{ut})]$} } ]
        at (axis cs:0.239017,638.115116) {};
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table},t]{beamer}    

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}
        

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes,calligraphy,plotmarks,overlay-beamer-styles}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
    
\begin{figure}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{axis}[
    legend style={at={(1.3,0)},draw=none,anchor= south, legend columns=1, font=\tiny,text width=1in, minimum height=0.2in}, 
    ymin=0,ymax=1000,
    xlabel = Strain ($\epsilon_{e}$ and $\epsilon_{t}$),
    every axis x label/.style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel = Stress ($F_{t}$ and $F_{e}$),
    every axis y label/.style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel},    
    xmin=0, xmax=0.4,
    xtick={0,0.05,...,0.4},,
x tick label style={rotate=45},
width=0.75\linewidth,
height=0.58\linewidth,
font=\tiny,    
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
]
\begin{scope}[
      every pin edge/.style={<-,>=latex, mark size=3pt},
      every pin/.append style={font=\tiny}
    ]

  
\addplot [black,mark = *,mark size=3pt,mark options={fill=black}, only marks] coordinates {(0.012,439) (0.182322,614.4) (0.2,512) (0.29,350)};

    
%\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.5,250)
    %{\tiny{(1) $\sigma_T=\ln*(1+\epsilon_{eng})$}};    
    
    
    %\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.12,650)
    %{\tiny{Eq. (1), (2)}};

        \node [coordinate,pin={[visible on=<2->,pin distance=0.35 in,pin edge={visible on=<2->,gray,thick}]90:{(5) $F_{t}=F_{ut}*[w*\frac{\epsilon_{t}}{\epsilon_{ut}}^n+(1-w)*(1+\epsilon_{t}-\epsilon_{ut})]$} } ]
            at (axis cs:0.239017,638.115116) {};
          
        \node[coordinate,pin={[pin distance=0.25 in,pin edge={gray,thick}]90:{(4) $F_{t}=F_{ut}*(\frac{\epsilon_{t}}{\epsilon_{ut}})^n$} } ]
            at (axis cs:0.095,565) {};            

    \node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.03,400)
    {\tiny{A}};

    \node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.18,450)
    {\tiny{B}};

    %\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.33,350)
    %{\tiny{C}};
    
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.182322,680)
    {\tiny{B'}};    

    \node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.1,160)
    {\tiny{Hardening Region}};    

    \addplot [<->, black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0.012,439)  (0.012,0)};
    \addplot [<->, black,dashed, thick] coordinates {(0.2,512)  (0.2,0)};
    \addplot [<->, black, thick] coordinates {(0.012,100)  (0.2,100)};

    \addplot [<->, black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0.29,350)  (0.29,0)};
    \addplot [<->, black, thick] coordinates {(0.2,100)  (0.29,100)};
    
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.245,160)
    {\tiny{Necking}};    
    
        %\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.245,180)
    %{\tiny$\begin{aligned} Necking, and \\ Fracture \end{aligned}$};    
    
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.31,350)
    {\tiny{C}}; 

\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{True Stress Strain Match}
\label{Tension_Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```